# Can't bind to View's property

Tags: wpf

In my view's xaml file， I have this line:

```
TextBox Text="{Binding MyModel.Text}"
```

Everytime I ran the program, it gave me this error message:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
>   'MyModel' property not found on 'object' ''MyModel'
>   (HashCode=56593137)'. BindingExpression:Path=MyModel.Text;
>   DataItem='MyModel' (HashCode=56593137); target element is 'TextBox'
>   (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

I'm sure my spelling is right.

I set my view's DataContext to ViewModel. Could that be a problem?

Answer (score 2):

If your `DataContext` is set to `MyModel` you should just have to write:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text}"/>
```

Adding the extra `MyModel` is repetitive and results in looking for `MyModel.MyModel.Text`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're view is bound to your view-model (good), then your view-model needs to have a property that your view will bind to:

```
TextBox Text="{Binding MyViewModelsProperty}"
```

In your situation, you'll need to set your model's property from your view-model (MyViewModelsProperty setter).

Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: I created a "wrapper" property in my viewmodel.

Comment: but it looks like it's always trying to find the property in model

Comment: System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Textt' property not found on 'object' ''MyModel' (HashCode=35353884)'. BindingExpression:Path=Textt; DataItem='MyModel' (HashCode=35353884); target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

Comment: @user1447343...Probably because the way you have it your xaml example.  Please post you view-model's property that you're trying to bind to.

Comment: @user1447343...Is 'Textt' really your property?

Comment: Yes. public string Textt
        {
            get
            {
                return SelectedTab.Text;
            }

            set
            {
                SelectedTab.Text = value;
            }
        }

Comment: I intentionally spelled it Textt so I knew exactly where it looked for property

Comment: You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your view-model and call OnPropertyChanged("Textt") in your property setter

Comment: @user1447343...At this point I think you need to post your code: xaml and view-model.

Answer (score 0):

Just `TextBox Text="{Binding Text}"`